# What is the magic behind the TCL command expr with the operator eq

Tags: tcl

I would like to understand the TCL command expr for string comparison:

I tried the following:

```
expr {t eq t}
=> 1
expr {tru eq tr}
=> 0
expr {tru eq truee}
=> invalid bareword "truee" ...
expr {a eq a}
=> invalid bareword "a" ...
```

What is the magic behind the words t, tr, tru? Does Tcl special handling for these strings? I learnt that I had to quote the string if I use expr with eq, but I have some legacy programs which use this form of comparison. I would like to understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In `Tcl`, `eq` and `ne` does the string comparison while `==` does the numerical comparison.

```
% expr {1 == 1.0}
1
% expr {1 eq 1.0}
0
%
```

Whenever you are using the `eq` and if the input non-numeric, then it should be used with double quotes or with a variable reference. **You can't use the literal bareword string notation.**

For e.g

```
% expr {"a" eq "b"}; # Strings with double quotes
0
% set i a
a
% expr {$i eq "a"}; # String with variable reference
1
% expr {a eq b}; # Literally using the string as bareword
invalid bareword "a"
in expression "a eq b";
should be "$a" or "{a}" or "a(...)" or ...
%
```

There is a exception in this rule, where the `Tcl` boolean comes into play.

In `Tcl`, a proper boolean value is either a proper integer, with, like in `C`, zero meaning false and non-zero meaning true, or one of the following:

```
yes, true, on   --> Boolean 1
no, false, off  --> Boolean 0
```

When they are used partially, Tcl tends to match with any of the known items and evaluation happens accordingly.

If you evaluate `expr` with these special words, then it will return the same.

```
% expr {true}
true
% expr {false}
false
% expr {t}; # Tcl automatically matches internally and map it to 'true'
t
% expr {fa} ; # Similary, mapped to 'false'
fa
% expr {o} ; # Will throw error as it is conflicting with 'on' & 'off'
invalid bareword "o"
in expression "o";
should be "$o" or "{o}" or "o(...)" or ...
% expr {on}
on
% expr {of}; # Matching 'off' boolean 
of

% if true {puts ya}
ya
% if n {puts ya}; # Matching boolean 'no'
% if f {puts ya}; # Matching boolean 'false'
% if false {puts ya}
% if yes {puts ya}
ya
% if y {puts ya}; # Matching boolean 'y'
ya
```

So, If your input is mapping with boolean, they are still valid, but treated as string only.

Now, lets go back to your original question.

```
% expr {t eq t}; # Tcl mapped the 'true' boolean and string-wise both are same. So, returned 1
1
% expr {tru eq tr}; # Both mapped 'true'. But, string-wise differs. So, returned 0
% expr {tru eq truee}; # 'tru' mapped to 'true' and 'truee' is unknown. So error
invalid bareword "truee"
% expr {a eq a}; # Both are used literally, so error throw.
invalid bareword "a"
```

Now, your question from the comments,

```
% expr {yes == true}; # String-wise, both are different. So, returned 0
0
```

Comment: I've added the details from the docs on Tcl_GetBoolean to expand your answer a bit as it didn't seem worth while creating a new answer for this level of clarification.  Please roll back the edit if you don't agree.

Comment: @Jackson: Have you tested it? Abbreviation does not work and generates an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand that the value is interpreted by tcl as boolean. However, why is `expr {yes == true}` returning '0'? I expected a '1'.

Comment: @tjroamer : Updated the whole answer. Please check. Hope it clarify the doubts.

Comment: @Dinesh, Yes, it is now quite clear. Thank you very much.